# Kafka Stream Reducer is not reducing records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Below is some sample code where we are trying to remove duplicates based on some record value (in this case id).  When I publish 2 records with the same ID I receive both print statements. I was expecting 1.  I am new to streams, so I am sure I am misunderstanding something.

```
 kstream.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getId())
                    .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> aggValue)
                    .toStream()
                    .foreach((key,value) -> {
                        System.out.println(value);
                    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reduce operation results in a ktable based on the defined adder.

```
KTable<Interger, String> aggregatedStream = kstream.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getId())
                    .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> aggValue)
```

SO kTable will have the latest value for the any ID (keys from value.getID()).

Kafka streams supports event by event processing. If the record cache is disabled, it will trigger the operation on each event. Hence the method is called twice for 2 records and print statement will return the latest value for that record.

An aggregation computes the sum of record values, grouped by key, for the input and returns a KTable.

Example :

**Without caching:** a sequence of output records is emitted for key A that represent changes in the resulting aggregation table. The parentheses (()) denote changes, the left number is the new aggregate value and the right number is the old aggregate value: `<A, (1, null)>, <A, (21, 1)>, <A, (321, 21)>.`

**With caching:** a single output record is emitted for key A that would likely be compacted in the cache, leading to a single output record of `<A, (321, null)>`. This record is written to the aggregation’s internal state store and forwarded to any downstream operations.

The cache size is specified through the `cache.max.bytes.buffering` parameter, which is a global setting per processing topology. You can set the property like this:

```
// Enable record cache of size 10 MB.
Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 10 * 1024 * 1024L);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - I see I was going about this the wrong way. I will post a new question with the real issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: Great. So if you think,  it solves your problem, you can accept the answer so that it can be helpful for other people :)

Comment: Thanks I did. Here is the new question in case you can answer it :-) . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526502/how-to-discover-and-filter-out-duplicate-records-in-kafka-streams

Comment: @Chris : Cool, Answered your other question. Please check if that solves your issue