# How to discover and filter out duplicate records in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Say you have a topic with a null key and the value is

```
{id:1, name:Chris, age:99}
```

Lets say you want to count up the number of people by name. You would do something like below:

```
nameStream.groupBy((key,value) -> value.getName())
           .count();
```

Now lets says it is valid you can get duplicate records and you can tell it is a duplicate based on the id.

For example:

```
{id:1, name:Chris, age:99}
{id:1, name:Chris, age:xx}
```

Should result in a count of one and

```
   {id:1, name:Chris, age:99}
   {id:2, name:Chris, age:xx}
```

should result in a count of 2.

How would you accomplish this?  I thought reduce would work, but misunderstood how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use more than one attribute for grouping. Create a custom key by concatenation and pass as key:

```
KTable<String,String> modifiedTable =  nameStream.groupBy((key,value) -> value.getName()+value.getId()).reduce((aggVal,newval) -> aggVal);
```

Above KTable will give the updated status for any record with the given name and ID. 
So for `{id:1,name:Chris.....}`, it will have only one  record in KTable:

While in below case, both records will be present:

```
<Chris1,  {id:1, name:Chris, age:99}> 
<Chris2,   {id:2, name:Chris, age:xx}>
```

Now you want to use the name attribute for count operation. So Change the key to **name** and re-group the table and perform count().

```
KTable countTable = modifiedTable.groupBy((k,v)-> KeyValue.pair(v.getName(), v)).count();
```

Here count() will be performed on top of KTable. KTable is the updated view for any given ID.
Hence for below input, modifiedTable will have 1 record at a time as updated value for key "Chris1" and you will get **count=>1**

```
<Chris,1> // Here key will be Chris1
```

Below input will result **count=>2

```
{id:1, name:Chris, age:99}  // Here key was be Chris1
{id:2, name:Chris, age:xx}  // Here key was be Chris2
```

Comment: Thanks Nishu.  Why do we need the reduce?  Also I am unsure if this will work if we have multiple partitions/threads.  Chris1 and Chris2 now can get hashed to different threads resulting in incorrect counts.

Comment: You can either use aggregate() or reduce(). Since the value type is not modified, reduce() will work. If you need to modify the value type, use aggregate().  You are right that Chris1 and Chris2 can be in different partitions. But before performing count(), there is a groupBy() operation called on name attribute. That will make sure that you get all the events for the given key from all partitions.

Comment: Yup that is actually what I did. :-) Starting to get it.

Comment: They key (no pun intended) was to use the combo of the name id and the topic key.